# sending emails with heirloom, even when Postfix is not running locally

Tags: email, postfix, mail-command

Normally, I can send email from commandline, such as

```
echo hello | mail -s "subject" user@example.com
```

I have noticed that even when Postfix is not running on my machine, I can still "send" emails. Actually they are being queued in `/var/spool/postfix/maildrop`. But once Postfix is started again, these emails will be sent out.

Can somebody please explain how this works? Who copies the emails into `/var/spool/postfix/maildrop`, is it the email client (`heirloom` in my case) ?

Does it mean, I have a guarantee all emails will be always delivered, regardless whether Postfix is running or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can somebody please explain how this works? Who copies the emails into
>   /var/spool/postfix/maildrop, is it the email client (heirloom in my
>   case) ?

Local mail submissions, are received with the `Postfix sendmail` compatibility command, are queued in `maildrop` queue by `postdrop` program.

The `postdrop` command is designed to run with set-group ID privileges, so that it
can write to the `maildrop` queue directory and connect to Postfix daemon processes.

> Does it mean, I have a guarantee all emails will be always delivered,
>   regardless whether Postfix is running or not?

Yes, `postfix` never drops mails even when its mail system is down. Other helper daemons like `cron` will check if the Postfix daemons 
are down for whatever reason, so postfix mails should not be lost, either.

**Note**

- [How Postfix receives mail](http://www.postfix.org/OVERVIEW.html)
- [postdrop - Postfix mail posting utility](http://www.postfix.org/postdrop.1.html)
- [sendmail - Postfix to Sendmail compatibility interface](http://www.postfix.org/sendmail.1.html)